# Склонение фамилии Кривац

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли молдавская фамилия Кривац? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Если есть возможность, то лучше уточнить у носителя, но как правило, склонение подобных фамилий зависит от пола носителя.

У мужчины по 2 склонению: *Юра Кривац-Юры Криваца-Юру Криваца-Юре Кривацу-Юрой Кривацем-о Юре Криваце*.

Если носитель женщина, то фамилия во всех падежах остаётся неизменной: *Яна Кривац-Яны Кривац-Яну Кривац-Яне Кривац-Яной Кривац-о Яне Кривац*.